# why terminal get closed when putting a wrong command to background in linux

Tags: linux, background-process

By mistake I executed the following command in Linux

```sh
abc &
```

it suddenly exits my terminal.

Then I tried to put a call to a non-existing command in the background, and the same result happens again. I found that whenever we put a call to a non-existing command to background while in non-login shell the terminal gets closed.

Why it was happening? What was the actual thing done inside?

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in your shell startup scripts (`~/.bashrc` etc.)?

Comment: no i didn't set

Comment: Is your shell bash? if yes, what does `type command_not_found_handle` say?